# apache redirection to niginx based on domain name

Tags: apache, nginx, httpd.conf

I have got APP1 running on apache httd over port 80, which will be reached via **app1.abc.com** , and I have got another app running on nginx over 8080 port on the same server which can be reached via **app2.abc.com:8080**.

Infact both app1.abc.com and app2.abc.com mapped to same IP x.x.x.1. So now I would like to know if I can configure some redirect rule in apache like, when traffic comes from app2.abc.com, with out 8080 port specified I should be internally routing this to nginx over 8080 port based on the domain that I came from.

Any help on this would be greatly helpful.

**Update 1**
I have tried this apache reverse proxy config.
    
         ServerName app1.subdomain.domain.com
         ServerAlias app1-app

```
     ProxyPass / http://0.0.0.0:80/
     ProxyPassReverse / http://0.0.0.0:80/
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerName app11.app1.subdomain.domain.com
     ServerAlias vpstage-target

    ProxyPass / http://0.0.0.0:8080/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://0.0.0.0:8080/
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: You need to use a **reverse proxy**, have a search for that there should be plenty of examples about.

Comment: Thanks arco444, Update1 - tried reverse proxy with named virtual host in apache config. Can you help me in correcting this? I am always been taken to 8080 app

Comment: Thanks arco444, apache reverse proxy is working